# How to return list for mock in groovy spock test

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, junit, spock

I have a problem with returning list of desired objects from Spock Groovy mocked interface:

```
public interface SomeRepository {
    List<SomeObject> getAll();
}
```

So I want to mock that in class:

```
@CompileStatic
class SomeProcessor {
    private final SomeRepository repository

    SomeProcessor(SomeRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository
    }

    List<SomeObject> getAll() {
        return repository.all
    }
}
```

And I have that test:

```
class SomeProcessorSpec extends Specification {
    private final SomeRepository repository = Mock(SomeRepository)

    @Subject private final SomeProcessor processor = new SomeProcessor(repository)

    def 'should collect items from repository'() {
        given:
            List<SomeObject> expected = [new SomeObject(), new SomeObject()]
            repository.all >> expected

        when:
            List<SomeObject> actual = processor.all

        then:
            assertEquals(expected, actual)
    }
}
```

When I try to run that test I get an assertion error:

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
>   Expected :[com.example.SomeObject@1fa268de, com.example.SomeOjbect@4f6ee6e4]
>   Actual   :null

So it means that from `repository.all` method it returned `null` and not my expected list, which is confusing me. And the question is: how to actually return list from mocked instance when testing with spock and groovy?

Comment: `repository.all >> expected` looks like removal to me. try replacing it with `repository.all = new ArrayList( expected )`

Comment: I tested your code 1:1, the only thing I changed is `Object` instead of `SomeObject` and it works just fine, exactly like you expect it to work. I tried with Spock 1.0-groovy-2.4 and 1.1-groovy-2.4 and both worked just fine.

Comment: Btw, is this exact code that does not work for you or short PoC that tries to reflect your problem? Maybe you face similar problem to that one - https://github.com/kiview/spring-spock-mock-beans-demo/issues/1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try moving stubbing part to interaction check phase, e.g.

```
def 'should collect items from repository'() {
    given:
        List<SomeObject> expected = [new SomeObject(), new SomeObject()]

    when:
        List<SomeObject> actual = processor.all

    then:
        1 * repository.all >> expected

    and:
        expected == actual
}
```

Also you don't have to use JUnit's `assertEquals` - Groovy allows you to compare both objects with `==` operator.

I have checked your example in simple Spock based app and it worked fine. I tested it with Spock `0.7-groovy-2.0`, `1.0-groovy-2.4` and `1.2-groovy-2.4-SNAPSHOT`, worked with all Spock versions. Anyway I had some similar issues in the past and stubbing as interaction check did the trick in those cases. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to white-box testing better to test exactly the same what is implemented. `processor.all` returns the result of `repository.all` as is. So, better to test this fact.

Based on the correct code provided by Szymon Stepniak the test may be simplified to:

```
def 'should collect items from repository'() {
    given:
        def expected = []

    when:
        def actual = processor.all

    then:
        1 * repository.all >> expected

    and: 'make sure we got the same expected list instance'
        actual.is(expected)
}
```

where by `.is()` we verify the same references.

As result it doesn't mater what the list has, it can be just empty.